# How to Design a QTWidget Form using QTCreator at Design Time?

Tags: qt

how to Design a QTWidget Form using QTCreator at Design Time ?

I want to have One QgridLayout with 6 rows and each row can have controls like label,puttons,images etc.  and form should be scrollable.

Now my requirement is how to generate buttons at run time and place image,labels on top of that button . Place all the buttons in a grid at run time and that grid can dynamically grow depending on the Seach results provided with a Scroll bar.Pls find attached image above for my requirement.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know which version of Qt Creator you're using. Assuming the latest, you may want to go through the [Qt Designer Manual](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/designer-manual.html).

You can add items using [QGridLayout::addWidget()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgridlayout.html#addWidget) function in a grid layout dynamically.

You can customize QWidgets using [Style Sheets](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/stylesheet.html).

Also, check [Qt Examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/all-examples.html) and [Qt Tutorials](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/tutorials.html). You may find something useful.

Comment: @ thanks for the link. Now my requirement is how to generate buttons at run time and place image,labels on top of that button . Place all the buttons in a grid at run time and that grid can dynamically grow depending on the Seach results provided with a Scroll bar.Pls find attached image above for my requirement.

Comment: @user662285: check the links in my answers. you'll find lots of sample codes in Qt Examples and Qt Tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Create everything firstly using visual tools like Qt Creator, compile, then copy the code it generated and paste it in your program.